# Python split on the partition list

Tags: python, split, partition

I am currently on a project that gat all partition on a disk with Ubuntu 20.

```py
def get_partitions():
    """
    This function returns a list of partition objects.
    """
    partitions = []
    for line in open('/proc/partitions'):
        if line.startswith('major'):
            continue
        fields = line.split()
        partitions.append(partition(
            int(fields[0]),
            int(fields[1]),
            int(fields[3]),
            fields[5]
        ))
    return partitions
```

But I have this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/mathieu-s/Documents/opt/repo/dosm/disk/disk_scanner.py", line 69, in <module>
    print(get_partitions())
  File "/home/mathieu-s/Documents/opt/repo/dosm/disk/disk_scanner.py", line 62, in get_partitions
    int(fields[0]),
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Someone can help me ?

Comment: `for line in open('/proc/partitions')` that's not how you read a file

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki why not?

Comment: The open() function returns a file object, which has a read() method for reading the content of the file.

Comment: Well, clearly `fields` has less elements than you expect it to have. That's what the error says. I suggest you print out `fields` in each iteration of the `for` loop to see why it might have less than six elements. That's all we can say.

Comment: @SembeiNorimaki, you can iterate over file descriptor.

Comment: The second line in the file is empty line, as well as the last one.

Comment: Beside the point, but Ubuntu 20 doesn't exist. You probably mean 20.04, but there's also Core 20 and 20.10.

Comment: What do you need help with exactly? Do you know why the error is happening? Or if not, do you know how to start debugging this? Please [edit] to clarify. For tips, see [ask].

Comment: I'm looking at `/proc/partitions` on my Ubuntu 20.04 and it only has 4 columns, so it looks like even once you fix the `IndexError` at `fields[0]`, `fields[5]` will raise the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Errors explications

#### Main error

When you get partitions data from `/proc/partitions` in Ubuntu 20.04, you have approximately this output:

```
major minor  #blocks  name

   7        0       5956 loop0
   7        1          4 loop1
   7        2       9240 loop2
   7        3       9244 loop3
   7        4     151112 loop4
   7        5     135924 loop5
   7        6     283688 loop6
   7        7      63580 loop7
 259        0  500107608 nvme0n1
 259        1     834560 nvme0n1p1
 259        2    8388608 nvme0n1p2
 259        3  490883072 nvme0n1p3
   7        8     101824 loop8
```

You can look that the second line is empty, but in your code you didn't check this case.

#### Second error

The line partition data:

```
major minor  #blocks  name
   7        0       5956 loop0
```

When you get the fields for your row, you convert the 3rd field to `int`, but the 3rd field is the `name` of the partition. The conversion of `name` to `int` will not work.

And when you get the 5th field from the line, it will show an error because this field does not exist on Ubuntu 20.04's file partition.

---

### Possible solution

#### fix the first error: empty line

To solve the main error, you can simply modify your if condition with this:

```py
        if line.startswith('major') or line.startswith('\n'):
```

#### fix the second problem: field number

To solve the second problem, you can modify your code in the `append` with this:

```py
        partitions.append(partition(
            int(fields[0]),
            int(fields[1]),
            int(fields[2]),
            fields[3]
        ))
```

---

#### All code of a possible solution:

```py
def get_partitions():
    """
    This function returns a list of partition in the disk.
    """
    partitions = []
    for line in open('/proc/partitions'):
        if line.startswith('major') or line.startswith('\n'):
            continue
        fields = line.split()
        partitions.append(partition(
            int(fields[0]),
            int(fields[1]),
            int(fields[2]),
            fields[3]
        ))
    return partitions
```

Comment: thanks to you :)

Comment: Regarding the negative votes on your question, it is important to give more details. Especially on the Ubuntu version, saying Ubuntu 20 is too ambiguous. Versions 20.04 and 20.10 are not identical.
And give more detail on the desired answer, just understand the error or have a solution? Or other ?